# Unity3D Compile Error: Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

i got a problem to build my android APK.

I've saw some question with the same error, but everything is about Google Play Services.

In my case i have the same error but with my own Plugin. The error i'ts from the Android Manifest.xml, and i need know how i can resolve it.

In some forums i'd see the solutions like; Update the building tools (i'm do it)
and add some lines to the AndroidManifest.xml....but these lines, are to Google Play Service...i must rewrite to my own Plugin.

Any idea?

I paste the error and another solutions for reference;

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/834744/building-android-application-failed-re-package-res.html

ERROR OUTPUT:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\ppalma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/ppalma/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[
AndroidManifest.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar').

]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  drawable\app_icon.png
    Src: () res\drawable\app_icon.png
  values\strings.xml
    Src: () res\values\strings.xml
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
  Type drawable
    drawable\app_icon.png
      Src: () res\drawable\app_icon.png
  Type values
    values\strings.xml
      Src: () res\values\strings.xml
Including resources from package: C:\Users\ppalma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
applyFileOverlay for layout
applyFileOverlay for anim
applyFileOverlay for animator
applyFileOverlay for interpolator
applyFileOverlay for transition
applyFileOverlay for xml
applyFileOverlay for raw
applyFileOverlay for color
applyFileOverlay for menu
applyFileOverlay for mipmap
Processing image: res\drawable\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable\app_icon.png: 90% size of source)
    (new resource id app_icon from drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
]
```